# Gmail authentication not returning to application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I've implemented gmail login using Firebase and am successfully able to have the user authenticate his email after pressing a custom button which has the action `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` connected.

However, once the user allows basic profile access it does not return to the app, it just goes to this screen:

[image: login]

Does anybody know how to make it go back to the app after the user authenticates? This is my console:

```
017-01-09 09:47:46.565367 Dog_Log[3922:829530] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-01-09 09:47:53.702 Dog_Log[3922:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: Dog_Log.AppDelegate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:**

The warning tells you that the Implementation of `application(_:open:options:)` can't be found:

```
2017-01-09 09:47:53.702 Dog_Log[3922:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Implementation of application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not found. Please add the handler into your App Delegate. Class: Dog_Log.AppDelegate
```

**Solution:**

You probably forgot the `application(_:open:options:)` method to implement, with calling the `handle(_:sourceApplication:annotation:)` in it, which handles the redirect to your application. Your `AppDelegate.swift` should look like this (hints are in the code comments):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // configure firebase
    FIRApp.configure()

    // configure google
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID

    return true
  }

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    // handled to go back to application after google log in
    let handled = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: [:])

    return handled
  }

  // other methods
}
```

Example ViewController which you make conform to the GIDSignInUIDelegate and GIDSignInDelegate, to access the signIn method and use it with an @IBAction of a custom button:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn


class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // make the view controller the delegate
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
  }

  // your action of the button to call the signIn method
  @IBAction func pressGoogleSignInButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
  }

  func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
      print("failed to log into google: ", error)
      return
    }

    print("successfully logged into google ", user)

    guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
    guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
    let credentials = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Faild to create a firebase user with google account: ", error)
        return
      }

      guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
      print("Successfully logged into firebase with google ", uid)
      // redirect to the next screen after successful login

    })
  }
}
```

Comment: So if this should be my AppDelegate.swift, for the ViewController should I just have the `IBAction` that calls `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()`?

Comment: @MarksCode updated my answer, so you can use the method in an IBAction of a button in a specific view controller

Comment: Yeah, great that I could help you!